# What does “格” mean in "爾國臨格"?

Tags: translation, meaning, characters, meaning-in-context, classical-chinese

Matthew 6:10 of the Bible is translated as the following in the Delegates Version:

爾國臨格、爾旨得成、在地若天、

The context was Jesus was teaching how to pray and gave an example of a prayer.

I fail to understand the meaning of 格 here. It seems to me "爾國臨" is a complete sentence. Why "爾國臨**格**" and what does "格" mean here?

Edit: The expected English translation is “thy kingdom come, thy will be done, on earth as it is in heaven”.

Comment: You should provide the expected translation: “thy kingdom come, thy will be done, on earth as it is in heaven”

Comment: it's probably shortened for 格外 = especially

Comment: The Delegate version is out of print. I got mine from Taiwan over 30 years ago and it was one of the last few copies available in Taiwan. Where did you got your copy?

Comment: @DanielLai I am unable to get a printed copy; there is a pdf version at https://www.scribd.com/document/31894180/%E6%96%B0%E8%88%8A%E7%B4%84%E8%81%96%E6%9B%B8-%E6%B7%B1%E6%96%87%E7%90%86-%E5%A7%94%E8%BE%A6%E8%AD%AF%E6%9C%AC-1908-%E5%85%89%E7%B7%92%E4%B8%89%E5%8D%81%E5%9B%9B%E5%B9%B4-High-Wenli-Delegate-s-Version-pdf#download.

Comment: @DanielLai To me the language is much more beautiful than all modern translations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the verse is chopped wrongly lah, i would read it as "爾" + "國" + "臨格".

"臨格" ought to be read together as a verb, with the meaning of "come / arrive".

the entry of "格" in 國語辭典 explained (the sixth, as verb):

> 至、來。《書經．堯典》：「光被四表，格於上下。」宋．蘇軾〈賀時宰啟〉：「歡聲格於九天，乖氣消於萬彙。」

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=W00000003946

for comparison, consider the word ["蒞臨"](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000062444), which means ~ "come / arrive / be present"; while the character ["蒞"](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=W00000003454) means "to reach / arrive", and ["臨"](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=W00000003654) means "come to / arrive / be present".

the main prayer text is translated by mr 王韜, imo, excellent one.

http://www.rhenish.org/Common/Reader/News/ShowNews.jsp?Nid=3782&Pid=5&Version=80&Cid=151&Charset=big5_hkscs

usages of "臨格" in literatures of yore:

in 文忠集　卷八十六

> 皇帝親詣啓聖禪院告遷明徳元徳章穆皇后赴普安院奉安祝文
>
> 嚮者因霖災之為沴・飭殿構以増新・㳙榖旦之惟良・奉神遊而還止・載深感慕・躬薦芬馨・式慰孝思・冀茲臨格

[image]

in 廬山太平興動宮採訪真君事實, the 滿散詞:

> 惟廬嶽之名峰，實天仙之奧宅。夢符晝現，雖自開元之傳；邇遠名彰，邈想真王之始。應世則帝王之佐，在天惟耳目之司。千齡昔紀於元豐，四字首加於徽號。備玆褥禮，屬在休期。鏤玉填金，煥成章於雲漢；臨軒發冊，增偉觀於江山。顧熙事之嘉成，涓良辰而祝告。伏願威神臨格，昭鑒居飲。薰燎揭虔，共仰九霄之邃；厲鴻嘖祉，永言萬壽之期。併敷錫於庶民，俾交欣於百樂。

[http://www.ctcwri.idv.tw/CTCW-CMTS/CMT07正乙部/CMT07ALL/CH07094盧山太平興國宮採訪真君事實/CH07094-2卷二宋朝崇奉類.htm](http://www.ctcwri.idv.tw/CTCW-CMTS/CMT07%E6%AD%A3%E4%B9%99%E9%83%A8/CMT07ALL/CH07094%E7%9B%A7%E5%B1%B1%E5%A4%AA%E5%B9%B3%E8%88%88%E5%9C%8B%E5%AE%AE%E6%8E%A1%E8%A8%AA%E7%9C%9F%E5%90%9B%E4%BA%8B%E5%AF%A6/CH07094-2%E5%8D%B7%E4%BA%8C%E5%AE%8B%E6%9C%9D%E5%B4%87%E5%A5%89%E9%A1%9E.htm)

have fun :)

Comment: This is a great answer and I love it! It explains the meaning clearly with references. Thank you for your effort!

Comment: @zuriel, you're welcome. indeed, the whole 主禱文 is extreme well translated, i like it very much, though i'm a atheist.

Answer (score 1):

[Baidu](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/379016374.html) has that in a more modern form:

愿你的国降临，愿你的旨意行在地上，如同行在天上。

They put 降临 where you have 臨格

降临： 来到， 光临

**Adveniat** regnum tuum (adveniat: 3rd person singular conjunctive of advenī́re)

Go with Drooze: 臨格 = come (subjunctive)

I like the Chinese version that you have!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The Delegate's Version is elegant but unfortunately out of print. Since the old English KJV is still popular, I am hoping that the old Chinese Delegate's Version can regain its popularity.